# Удаление объекта из памяти в javascript

Tags: javascript

Имеется динамический сайт из 10 страниц (работает по средствам `history API`). При переходе на первую страницу динамически подгружается `.js` файл, который содержит объект, который выполняет определенные действия на странице. То же самое и для других страниц, при переходе на любую из 10 страниц подгружается свой объект со своими методами и свойствами.

Так вот, нужно, чтобы при переходе на другие страницы объект безвозвратно удалялся и не висел в памяти.

Как правильно удалять объект? Вот так: `obj = null;` или `obj = {};`

Или же имеются другой способ, более правильный?

Если удалять объекты указанными мной способами, то через какое, примерно, время сборщик мусора окончательно удалит сами объекты?

И еще такой вопрос:

Если вместо объекта будет функция, то как её правильно удалить? Так: `func = null;`

Я хотел бы положиться на ваш опыт в разработке динамический приложений. Как бы вы реализовали механизм работы подобного приложения?

Comment: Боюсь, что на этот вопрос однозначного ответа просто не существует. Это выполняется у пользователей с разными наборами железа и софта, а сборщик "ничего не должен".

Answer (score 1):

> Как правильно удалять объект? Вот так: obj = null; или obj = {};

В обоих случая останется ссылка `obj`, которая будет казывать на что-то. Удалить её полностью можно так:

```
delete obj;
```

Объект же, который был по ссылке, удалится только когда до него доберётся сборщик мусора, поведение которого зависит, например, от браузера. Ускорить этот процесс, насколько мне известно, в общем случае нельзя.

Вот хорошая [статья](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/) (на английском) про оптимизацию памяти в javascript.

Comment: если в воркере держать динамические данные то и может и можно ускорить :)

Comment: "Ensure that you’re unbinding event listeners where they are no longer required, especially when the DOM objects they’re bound to are about to be removed" я недавно проверял это в хроме - память занятая скопом листенера освобождается при удалении объекта.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, насколько это законно... Если объект подгружается из файла в тег `<script>` и на него есть ссылка, то `removeChild()`, вроде бы, удаляет объект без следа. Пусть гуру подведут теоретическую базу.

В моём случае объекты с одноименной функцией вызова загружались через xmlhttp в `<head><script>...</script></head>`. Если в этот же скрипт загрузить новое содержимое через `innerHTML`, вызывается старый объект из памяти, несмотря на `obj = null`, `obj = {};` и даже `delete Object`. А если удалить `script`(removeChild) и приаттачить к head новый `appendCild(createElement('script'))`- вызывается уже новый конструктор, несмотря на то, что имя у него такое же, как и у предыдущего.

Отсюда вывод - объект таким способом удаляется со всеми `__proto__` и прочими цепочками.